# How to make a Global Contour around White Pixels - Python Open CV?

Tags: python, opencv, datetime, image-processing, computer-vision

In the picture, you can see that Red Contours have been drawn around individual White Pixels. Is there any method I can draw a Global Contour across all the Pixels (White Pixels)?
[image]

Comment: Edit your question: what is a global contour? Add a sample with few points and show what you think the result should be.

Comment: And always include the original uncompressed image to be processed.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for the [convex hull](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d3/dc0/group__imgproc__shape.html#ga014b28e56cb8854c0de4a211cb2be656) of the points.

This is an opencv [tutorial](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d7/d1d/tutorial_hull.html) on how to draw the convex hull of groups of points.